# How to catch possible error message and transfer it to sweet alert

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert

On delete button I display sweet alert which is working ok. The problem is that when I send object id which does not exist, I'm getting the same message (that I delete successfully).

What I want is to show a message if any error occurs (e.g. event with that id is not found, I want to create new message and display it as a sweet alert).

```
$('.deleteEvent').on('click', function () {
    var $button = $(this);
    var id = $button.data('id');
    console.log("id", id);
    var config = {
        title: 'Are you sure',
        type: 'info',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: ' No',
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: true
    };

    swal(config, function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            console.log("lokac", window.location.origin);
            var url = window.location.origin + '/events/delete?id=' + id;
            $.post(url)
                .done(function () {
                    var doneConfig = {
                        title: 'Succ....',
                        type: 'success',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
                    };

                    sweetAlert(doneConfig, function (done) {
                        if (done) {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                })
                .fail(function (error) {
                    var errorConfig = {
                        title: 'Not Found',
                        type: 'error',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
                    };
                    sweetAlert(errorConfig, function (done) {
                        if (done) {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                });
        }
    });
});
```

And my controller

```
 public ActionResult Delete(int id)
 {
        if (id == default(int))
            return RedirectToRoute(AppRoute.Events.EventsRoute);
        id = -1;
     try
      {
            var event = 
        DbContext.Event.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EventId == id);

            if (event == null)
            {
             //If event is not found, I want to create a message which
             //will be displayed on sweet alert                   
            }
      }
   //.....
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take into account that for execute the fail function the HTTP Status code must be different than 200 OK, so for example, in your controller if something fails you can return HTTP Status Code 500 (Internal Server Error) and it will execute the fail function.

In your example must be something like:

```
if (event == null)
  {
     //If event is not found, I want to create a message which
     //will be displayed on sweet alert   
     return HttpStatusCodeResult(500)
  }
```

If you want to show different messages you should capture the HTTP Status Code in your .done and .fail functions and show a message depending of what you are getting from the server